# Error:(19, 22) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Tags: java

Пробую писать сумму элементов массива, сначала использовал int, всё работало, потом решил поменять на byte и мне выдало ошибку.

```
public class SumArrDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                byte[] array = new byte[3];
        byte sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Write your digits:");
        for (byte i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            array[i] = scanner.nextByte();
        }
        for( byte num : array)
        {
            sum = sum+num;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum equals: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Я читал о преобразовании типов и что из byte в int можно, а обратно нельзя. Что мне тогда нужно сделать, если я хочу попробовать использовать тип данных byte?

Comment: На какой строчке?

Comment: На 15 строчке выдал ошибку.

Comment: "На 15 строчке" - считая откуда :( ?

Comment: Считая со строки с классом

Comment: IntelliJ предложила мне вариант решения этой проблемы, я выбрал "Cast to Byte", строка превратилась в "sum = (byte) (sum+num);". Можете объяснить, что, по сути, произошло и почему мне сразу не давали изменить на Byte?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

то есть

> В других случаях оба операнда преобразуются в тип `int`.

Таким образом, в Джаве нельзя получить что-то по размеру меньше целого, складывая числа.